# Trouble installing MatLab R2015A on elementary OS

Tags: software-installation

I'm having trouble installing MatLab R2015A on elementary OS Loki. Can anyone help ?!

**Here's the log I got:**

```
(Nov 30, 2016 13:19:11) ##################################################################
(Nov 30, 2016 13:19:11) #
(Nov 30, 2016 13:19:11) # Today's Date: 
(Nov 30, 2016 13:19:11) Wed Nov 30 13:19:10 BRST 2016
(Nov 30, 2016 13:19:11) 
(Nov 30, 2016 13:19:11) System Info
(Nov 30, 2016 13:19:11) OS: Linux 4.4.0-47-generic
(Nov 30, 2016 13:19:11) Arch: amd64
(Nov 30, 2016 13:19:11) Data Model: 64
(Nov 30, 2016 13:19:11) Language: pt
(Nov 30, 2016 13:19:11) Java Vendor: Oracle Corporation
(Nov 30, 2016 13:19:11) Java Home: /tmp/mathworks_7662/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre
(Nov 30, 2016 13:19:11) Java Version: 1.7.0_60
(Nov 30, 2016 13:19:11) Java VM Name: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
(Nov 30, 2016 13:19:11) Java Class Path: .
(Nov 30, 2016 13:19:11) User Name: root
(Nov 30, 2016 13:19:11) Current Directory: /home/franciscone/MatlaLinux/Matlab
(Nov 30, 2016 13:19:11) Input arguments: 
(Nov 30, 2016 13:19:11) root /home/franciscone/MatlaLinux/Matlab
(Nov 30, 2016 13:19:11) libdir /tmp/mathworks_7662
(Nov 30, 2016 13:19:11) standalone true
(Nov 30, 2016 13:19:12) Starting local product/component search in download directory
(Nov 30, 2016 13:19:12) Searching for archives...
(Nov 30, 2016 13:19:12) Reading /home/franciscone/MatlaLinux/Matlab/archives
(Nov 30, 2016 13:19:13) 4353 files found in /home/franciscone/MatlaLinux/Matlab/archives
(Nov 30, 2016 13:19:13) Reading /home/franciscone/MatlaLinux/Matlab
(Nov 30, 2016 13:19:13) 15 files found in /home/franciscone/MatlaLinux/Matlab
(Nov 30, 2016 13:19:13) /root/Downloads/MathWorks/R2015a/archives doesn't exist ... skipping.
(Nov 30, 2016 13:19:13) Archive search complete.  4368 total files found.
(Nov 30, 2016 13:19:37) Completed local product/component search
(Nov 30, 2016 13:19:37) java.io.FileNotFoundException: File '/home/franciscone/MatlaLinux/Matlab/archives/glnxa64/idelink/errorhandler_resources_glnxa64_1419898838.xml' does not exist
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.openInputStream(FileUtils.java:299)
    at com.mathworks.install.input.FileInputStreamProvider.getInputStream(FileInputStreamProvider.java:20)
    at com.mathworks.install.XMLInstallationFileParserImpl.readInDefinition(XMLInstallationFileParserImpl.java:94)
    at com.mathworks.install.input.AbstractInstallationInputFile.readInDefinitions(AbstractInstallationInputFile.java:82)
    at com.mathworks.install.input.AbstractInstallationInputFile.parse(AbstractInstallationInputFile.java:68)
    at com.mathworks.install.AbstractSoftwareManagerBuilder$2.call(AbstractSoftwareManagerBuilder.java:79)
    at com.mathworks.install.AbstractSoftwareManagerBuilder$2.call(AbstractSoftwareManagerBuilder.java:74)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

(Nov 30, 2016 13:19:37) java.io.FileNotFoundException: File '/home/franciscone/MatlaLinux/Matlab/archives/glnxa64/idelink/errorhandler_resources_glnxa64_1419898838.xml' does not exist
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.openInputStream(FileUtils.java:299)
    at com.mathworks.install.input.FileInputStreamProvider.getInputStream(FileInputStreamProvider.java:20)
    at com.mathworks.install.XMLInstallationFileParserImpl.readInDefinition(XMLInstallationFileParserImpl.java:94)
    at com.mathworks.install.input.AbstractInstallationInputFile.readInDefinitions(AbstractInstallationInputFile.java:82)
    at com.mathworks.install.input.AbstractInstallationInputFile.parse(AbstractInstallationInputFile.java:68)
    at com.mathworks.install.AbstractSoftwareManagerBuilder$2.call(AbstractSoftwareManagerBuilder.java:79)
    at com.mathworks.install.AbstractSoftwareManagerBuilder$2.call(AbstractSoftwareManagerBuilder.java:74)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

(Nov 30, 2016 13:19:37) Warning: The following files do not appear to be valid archives:

/home/franciscone/MatlaLinux/Matlab/archives/glnxa64/mwcontents_Simulink85_glnxa64.xml
/home/franciscone/MatlaLinux/Matlab/archives/glnxa64/mwcontents_MATLAB_Coder28_glnxa64.xml
(Nov 30, 2016 13:19:52) Default Installation Folder: /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a
(Nov 30, 2016 13:19:58) Confirmation Text: 
Installation folder:
/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a

Installation Size: 10.328 MB

Products:
MATLAB Distributed Computing Server 6.6
MATLAB 8.5
Simulink 8.5
Aerospace Blockset 3.15
Aerospace Toolbox 2.15
Antenna Toolbox 1.0
Bioinformatics Toolbox 4.5.1
Communications System Toolbox 6.0
Computer Vision System Toolbox 6.2
Control System Toolbox 9.9
Curve Fitting Toolbox 3.5.1
Database Toolbox 5.2.1
Datafeed Toolbox 5.1
DO Qualification Kit 2.5
DSP System Toolbox 9.0
Econometrics Toolbox 3.2
Embedded Coder 6.8
Filter Design HDL Coder 2.9.7
Financial Instruments Toolbox 2.1
Financial Toolbox 5.5
Fixed-Point Designer 5.0
Fuzzy Logic Toolbox 2.2.21
Global Optimization Toolbox 3.3.1
HDL Coder 3.6
HDL Verifier 4.6
IEC Certification Kit 3.5
Image Acquisition Toolbox 4.9
Image Processing Toolbox 9.2
Instrument Control Toolbox 3.7
LTE System Toolbox 2.0
Mapping Toolbox 4.1
MATLAB Coder 2.8
MATLAB Compiler 6.0
MATLAB Compiler SDK 6.0
MATLAB Production Server 2.1
MATLAB Report Generator 4.1
Model Predictive Control Toolbox 5.0.1
Neural Network Toolbox 8.3
Optimization Toolbox 7.2
Parallel Computing Toolbox 6.6
Partial Differential Equation Toolbox 2.0
Phased Array System Toolbox 3.0
Polyspace Bug Finder 1.3
Polyspace Code Prover 9.3
RF Toolbox 2.16
Robotics System Toolbox 1.0
Robust Control Toolbox 5.3
Signal Processing Toolbox 7.0
SimBiology 5.2
SimDriveline 2.8
SimElectronics 2.7
SimEvents 4.4
SimHydraulics 1.16
SimMechanics 4.6
SimPowerSystems 6.3
SimRF 4.4
Simscape 3.13
Simulink 3D Animation 7.3
Simulink Code Inspector 2.3
Simulink Coder 8.8
Simulink Control Design 4.2
Simulink Design Optimization 2.7
Simulink Design Verifier 2.8
Simulink Report Generator 4.1
Simulink Test 1.0
Simulink Verification and Validation 3.9
Stateflow 8.5
Statistics and Machine Learning Toolbox 10.0
Symbolic Math Toolbox 6.2
System Identification Toolbox 9.2
SystemTest 2.6.9
Vision HDL Toolbox 1.0
Wavelet Toolbox 4.14.1

(Nov 30, 2016 13:20:04) java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.mathworks.install.ComponentSizeAggregator.add(ComponentSizeAggregator.java:13)
    at com.mathworks.install.ProductInstallerImpl.downloadProducts(ProductInstallerImpl.java:96)
    at com.mathworks.install.ProductInstallerImpl.installProducts(ProductInstallerImpl.java:57)
    at com.mathworks.install.InstallerImpl.install(InstallerImpl.java:100)
    at com.mathworks.installwizard.model.InstallTask.execute(InstallTask.java:46)
    at com.mathworks.installwizard.model.AbstractBackgroundTask.execute(AbstractBackgroundTask.java:38)
    at com.mathworks.installwizard.model.AbstractTask.call(AbstractTask.java:73)
    at com.mathworks.installwizard.model.AbstractTask.call(AbstractTask.java:23)
    at com.mathworks.wizard.worker.WorkerImpl.doInBackground(WorkerImpl.java:24)
    at javax.swing.SwingWorker$1.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.SwingWorker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

(Nov 30, 2016 13:20:04) Error: The application encountered an unexpected error and needs to close.  You may want to try re-installing your product(s).  More information can be found at /tmp/mathworks_root.log
(Nov 30, 2016 13:20:07) Exiting with status -1
(Nov 30, 2016 13:20:07) End - Unsuccessful.
(Nov 30, 2016 13:20:22) ##################################################################
(Nov 30, 2016 13:20:22) #
(Nov 30, 2016 13:20:22) # Today's Date: 
(Nov 30, 2016 13:20:22) Wed Nov 30 13:20:22 BRST 2016
(Nov 30, 2016 13:20:22) 
(Nov 30, 2016 13:20:22) System Info
(Nov 30, 2016 13:20:22) OS: Linux 4.4.0-47-generic
(Nov 30, 2016 13:20:22) Arch: amd64
(Nov 30, 2016 13:20:22) Data Model: 64
(Nov 30, 2016 13:20:22) Language: pt
(Nov 30, 2016 13:20:22) Java Vendor: Oracle Corporation
(Nov 30, 2016 13:20:22) Java Home: /tmp/mathworks_8192/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre
(Nov 30, 2016 13:20:22) Java Version: 1.7.0_60
(Nov 30, 2016 13:20:22) Java VM Name: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
(Nov 30, 2016 13:20:22) Java Class Path: .
(Nov 30, 2016 13:20:22) User Name: root
(Nov 30, 2016 13:20:22) Current Directory: /home/franciscone/MatlaLinux/Matlab
(Nov 30, 2016 13:20:22) Input arguments: 
(Nov 30, 2016 13:20:22) root /home/franciscone/MatlaLinux/Matlab
(Nov 30, 2016 13:20:22) libdir /tmp/mathworks_8192
(Nov 30, 2016 13:20:22) standalone true
(Nov 30, 2016 13:20:24) Starting local product/component search in download directory
(Nov 30, 2016 13:20:24) Searching for archives...
(Nov 30, 2016 13:20:24) Reading /home/franciscone/MatlaLinux/Matlab/archives
(Nov 30, 2016 13:20:24) 4353 files found in /home/franciscone/MatlaLinux/Matlab/archives
(Nov 30, 2016 13:20:24) Reading /home/franciscone/MatlaLinux/Matlab
(Nov 30, 2016 13:20:24) 15 files found in /home/franciscone/MatlaLinux/Matlab
(Nov 30, 2016 13:20:24) /root/Downloads/MathWorks/R2015a/archives doesn't exist ... skipping.
(Nov 30, 2016 13:20:24) Archive search complete.  4368 total files found.
(Nov 30, 2016 13:20:32) Completed local product/component search
(Nov 30, 2016 13:20:35) Default Installation Folder: /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a
(Nov 30, 2016 13:20:46) Default Installation Folder: /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a
(Nov 30, 2016 13:20:50) Confirmation Text: 
Installation folder:
/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a

Installation Size: 10.328 MB

Products:
MATLAB Distributed Computing Server 6.6
MATLAB 8.5
Simulink 8.5
Aerospace Blockset 3.15
Aerospace Toolbox 2.15
Antenna Toolbox 1.0
Bioinformatics Toolbox 4.5.1
Communications System Toolbox 6.0
Computer Vision System Toolbox 6.2
Control System Toolbox 9.9
Curve Fitting Toolbox 3.5.1
Database Toolbox 5.2.1
Datafeed Toolbox 5.1
DO Qualification Kit 2.5
DSP System Toolbox 9.0
Econometrics Toolbox 3.2
Embedded Coder 6.8
Filter Design HDL Coder 2.9.7
Financial Instruments Toolbox 2.1
Financial Toolbox 5.5
Fixed-Point Designer 5.0
Fuzzy Logic Toolbox 2.2.21
Global Optimization Toolbox 3.3.1
HDL Coder 3.6
HDL Verifier 4.6
IEC Certification Kit 3.5
Image Acquisition Toolbox 4.9
Image Processing Toolbox 9.2
Instrument Control Toolbox 3.7
LTE System Toolbox 2.0
Mapping Toolbox 4.1
MATLAB Coder 2.8
MATLAB Compiler 6.0
MATLAB Compiler SDK 6.0
MATLAB Production Server 2.1
MATLAB Report Generator 4.1
Model Predictive Control Toolbox 5.0.1
Neural Network Toolbox 8.3
Optimization Toolbox 7.2
Parallel Computing Toolbox 6.6
Partial Differential Equation Toolbox 2.0
Phased Array System Toolbox 3.0
Polyspace Bug Finder 1.3
Polyspace Code Prover 9.3
RF Toolbox 2.16
Robotics System Toolbox 1.0
Robust Control Toolbox 5.3
Signal Processing Toolbox 7.0
SimBiology 5.2
SimDriveline 2.8
SimElectronics 2.7
SimEvents 4.4
SimHydraulics 1.16
SimMechanics 4.6
SimPowerSystems 6.3
SimRF 4.4
Simscape 3.13
Simulink 3D Animation 7.3
Simulink Code Inspector 2.3
Simulink Coder 8.8
Simulink Control Design 4.2
Simulink Design Optimization 2.7
Simulink Design Verifier 2.8
Simulink Report Generator 4.1
Simulink Test 1.0
Simulink Verification and Validation 3.9
Stateflow 8.5
Statistics and Machine Learning Toolbox 10.0
Symbolic Math Toolbox 6.2
System Identification Toolbox 9.2
SystemTest 2.6.9
Vision HDL Toolbox 1.0
Wavelet Toolbox 4.14.1

(Nov 30, 2016 13:20:52) java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.mathworks.install.ComponentSizeAggregator.add(ComponentSizeAggregator.java:13)
    at com.mathworks.install.ProductInstallerImpl.downloadProducts(ProductInstallerImpl.java:96)
    at com.mathworks.install.ProductInstallerImpl.installProducts(ProductInstallerImpl.java:57)
    at com.mathworks.install.InstallerImpl.install(InstallerImpl.java:100)
    at com.mathworks.installwizard.model.InstallTask.execute(InstallTask.java:46)
    at com.mathworks.installwizard.model.AbstractBackgroundTask.execute(AbstractBackgroundTask.java:38)
    at com.mathworks.installwizard.model.AbstractTask.call(AbstractTask.java:73)
    at com.mathworks.installwizard.model.AbstractTask.call(AbstractTask.java:23)
    at com.mathworks.wizard.worker.WorkerImpl.doInBackground(WorkerImpl.java:24)
    at javax.swing.SwingWorker$1.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.SwingWorker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

(Nov 30, 2016 13:20:52) Error: The application encountered an unexpected error and needs to close.  You may want to try re-installing your product(s).  More information can be found at /tmp/mathworks_root.log
(Nov 30, 2016 13:20:59) Exiting with status -1
(Nov 30, 2016 13:21:00) End - Unsuccessful.
(Nov 30, 2016 13:21:17) ##################################################################
(Nov 30, 2016 13:21:17) #
(Nov 30, 2016 13:21:17) # Today's Date: 
(Nov 30, 2016 13:21:17) Wed Nov 30 13:21:17 BRST 2016
(Nov 30, 2016 13:21:17) 
(Nov 30, 2016 13:21:17) System Info
(Nov 30, 2016 13:21:17) OS: Linux 4.4.0-47-generic
(Nov 30, 2016 13:21:17) Arch: amd64
(Nov 30, 2016 13:21:17) Data Model: 64
(Nov 30, 2016 13:21:17) Language: pt
(Nov 30, 2016 13:21:17) Java Vendor: Oracle Corporation
(Nov 30, 2016 13:21:17) Java Home: /tmp/mathworks_8650/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre
(Nov 30, 2016 13:21:17) Java Version: 1.7.0_60
(Nov 30, 2016 13:21:17) Java VM Name: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
(Nov 30, 2016 13:21:17) Java Class Path: .
(Nov 30, 2016 13:21:17) User Name: root
(Nov 30, 2016 13:21:17) Current Directory: /home/franciscone/MatlaLinux/Matlab
(Nov 30, 2016 13:21:17) Input arguments: 
(Nov 30, 2016 13:21:17) root /home/franciscone/MatlaLinux/Matlab
(Nov 30, 2016 13:21:17) libdir /tmp/mathworks_8650
(Nov 30, 2016 13:21:17) standalone true
(Nov 30, 2016 13:21:19) Starting local product/component search in download directory
(Nov 30, 2016 13:21:19) Searching for archives...
(Nov 30, 2016 13:21:19) Reading /home/franciscone/MatlaLinux/Matlab/archives
(Nov 30, 2016 13:21:19) 4353 files found in /home/franciscone/MatlaLinux/Matlab/archives
(Nov 30, 2016 13:21:19) Reading /home/franciscone/MatlaLinux/Matlab
(Nov 30, 2016 13:21:19) 15 files found in /home/franciscone/MatlaLinux/Matlab
(Nov 30, 2016 13:21:19) /root/Downloads/MathWorks/R2015a/archives doesn't exist ... skipping.
(Nov 30, 2016 13:21:19) Archive search complete.  4368 total files found.
(Nov 30, 2016 13:21:27) Completed local product/component search
(Nov 30, 2016 13:21:33) Default Installation Folder: /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a
(Nov 30, 2016 13:21:40) Confirmation Text: 
Installation folder:
/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a

Installation Size: 10.328 MB

Products:
MATLAB Distributed Computing Server 6.6
MATLAB 8.5
Simulink 8.5
Aerospace Blockset 3.15
Aerospace Toolbox 2.15
Antenna Toolbox 1.0
Bioinformatics Toolbox 4.5.1
Communications System Toolbox 6.0
Computer Vision System Toolbox 6.2
Control System Toolbox 9.9
Curve Fitting Toolbox 3.5.1
Database Toolbox 5.2.1
Datafeed Toolbox 5.1
DO Qualification Kit 2.5
DSP System Toolbox 9.0
Econometrics Toolbox 3.2
Embedded Coder 6.8
Filter Design HDL Coder 2.9.7
Financial Instruments Toolbox 2.1
Financial Toolbox 5.5
Fixed-Point Designer 5.0
Fuzzy Logic Toolbox 2.2.21
Global Optimization Toolbox 3.3.1
HDL Coder 3.6
HDL Verifier 4.6
IEC Certification Kit 3.5
Image Acquisition Toolbox 4.9
Image Processing Toolbox 9.2
Instrument Control Toolbox 3.7
LTE System Toolbox 2.0
Mapping Toolbox 4.1
MATLAB Coder 2.8
MATLAB Compiler 6.0
MATLAB Compiler SDK 6.0
MATLAB Production Server 2.1
MATLAB Report Generator 4.1
Model Predictive Control Toolbox 5.0.1
Neural Network Toolbox 8.3
Optimization Toolbox 7.2
Parallel Computing Toolbox 6.6
Partial Differential Equation Toolbox 2.0
Phased Array System Toolbox 3.0
Polyspace Bug Finder 1.3
Polyspace Code Prover 9.3
RF Toolbox 2.16
Robotics System Toolbox 1.0
Robust Control Toolbox 5.3
Signal Processing Toolbox 7.0
SimBiology 5.2
SimDriveline 2.8
SimElectronics 2.7
SimEvents 4.4
SimHydraulics 1.16
SimMechanics 4.6
SimPowerSystems 6.3
SimRF 4.4
Simscape 3.13
Simulink 3D Animation 7.3
Simulink Code Inspector 2.3
Simulink Coder 8.8
Simulink Control Design 4.2
Simulink Design Optimization 2.7
Simulink Design Verifier 2.8
Simulink Report Generator 4.1
Simulink Test 1.0
Simulink Verification and Validation 3.9
Stateflow 8.5
Statistics and Machine Learning Toolbox 10.0
Symbolic Math Toolbox 6.2
System Identification Toolbox 9.2
SystemTest 2.6.9
Vision HDL Toolbox 1.0
Wavelet Toolbox 4.14.1

(Nov 30, 2016 13:21:41) java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.mathworks.install.ComponentSizeAggregator.add(ComponentSizeAggregator.java:13)
    at com.mathworks.install.ProductInstallerImpl.downloadProducts(ProductInstallerImpl.java:96)
    at com.mathworks.install.ProductInstallerImpl.installProducts(ProductInstallerImpl.java:57)
    at com.mathworks.install.InstallerImpl.install(InstallerImpl.java:100)
    at com.mathworks.installwizard.model.InstallTask.execute(InstallTask.java:46)
    at com.mathworks.installwizard.model.AbstractBackgroundTask.execute(AbstractBackgroundTask.java:38)
    at com.mathworks.installwizard.model.AbstractTask.call(AbstractTask.java:73)
    at com.mathworks.installwizard.model.AbstractTask.call(AbstractTask.java:23)
    at com.mathworks.wizard.worker.WorkerImpl.doInBackground(WorkerImpl.java:24)
    at javax.swing.SwingWorker$1.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.SwingWorker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

(Nov 30, 2016 13:21:41) Error: The application encountered an unexpected error and needs to close.  You may want to try re-installing your product(s).  More information can be found at /tmp/mathworks_root.log
(Nov 30, 2016 13:21:44) Exiting with status -1
(Nov 30, 2016 13:21:45) End - Unsuccessful.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you need a newer version of MatLab.

elementary OS Loki is based on Ubuntu 16.04, which is not supported by MatLab R2015A. According to the [MatLab System Requirements](https://www.mathworks.com/support/sysreq/current_release/index.html?sec=linux&s_tid=gn_loc_drop), "Ubuntu 16.04 is supported as of R2016b."

Comment: I just tried to install MATLAB R2015A on Ubuntu 15.04 and had the same issue. Shouldn't it work ?!

Comment: From the system requirements document, it seems like MatLab only supports Ubuntu LTS releases. That's 14.04 for R2015A, and 16.04 for R2016B.